# Strange result while perform reading 'first and last line' from cat output with 'head' and 'tail'

Tags: bash, sed, tail, head

Bash version 4.4.7.

From [tutorial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139089/how-to-read-first-and-last-line-from-cat-output/139099#139099), to get the first and the last lines of a file:

```
cat txt_file | (head -n1 && tail -n1)
```

but, for large file (I don't know how large this will work, but file with about thousands lines) this command runs well, but for small file, example:

```
11111111
22222222
33333333
44444444
```

The output of command about is only the first line:

```
11111111
```

The other command, using awk, works with both files:

```
awk 'NR==1; END{print}'
```

Comment: It doesn't seem a strange result to me at all ... its unlikely a `head && tail` will work unless the input is larger than whatever the buffer size.

Comment: @donkopotamus I don't know that, could you explain? And how to let head, tail work for this example! Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain how that works? Each commands loads one buffer at a time, tries to terminate with that buffer and then hands the remaining buffers to the next command? How large is the buffer size usually or how can I find that out?

Comment: @duqu: To make it work you could run `cat txt_file | head -n1; cat txt_file | tail -n1`

Comment: [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Also, `sed -n -e '1p;$p'` will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "question" at the moment is not actually posed as a question, its merely an observation.  To explain your observation however.  Consider the difference between the output of:

```
$ seq 10 | (head -1 && tail -1)
1
```

and

```
$ seq 1000 | (head -1 && tail -1)
1
1000
```

What is happening here?  Our pipeline is working as follows:

- send lines (in this case with numbers but its no different to your `cat` example) to stdout;
- reading stdout we have:

  - first, a `head` ... it will print the first line and then end;
  - next, a `tail` ... it will begin **after** the head has run and print the last line.

However, by default, `head` is **not reading the file line by line**, or even character by character till it finds a line break, instead its reading the file in chunks (a buffered read).  That chunk might be 2048 bytes for example.

So our pipeline is really:

- send lines (in this case with numbers but its no different to your `cat` example) to stdout;
- reading stdout we have:

  - first, a `head` ... it will read the first 2kb from stdin, print the first line and then end;
  - next, a `tail` ... it will read the remainder of the data **after that first 2k because it never sees it**.

If your goal is to only generate the output of the first command (your `cat`) once, then you could use `tee`, something like this perhaps:

```
$ seq 10 | tee >(tail -1) | head -2
```

Also note that on linux, you could alter the buffering of the first command, something like:

```
$ stdbuf -oL seq 10 | (head -1 && tail -1)
```

but this won't work if your command fiddles with its streams (see [stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf))

Answer (score 2):

try following too:
**sed solution:**

```
sed -n '1p;$p' <(seq 1000)
```

**perl solution:**

```
seq 100 |  perl -ne 'print if 1..1 or eof'
```

**bash solution with only tail:**

```
seq 100 | { IFS= read -r line; echo "$line"; tail -1; }
```